# MySQL query for selecting 2 same columns

Tags: mysql

Maybe I made wrong title, but problem is next.. i have 3 tables (Person, RealEstate, Contract) and then I want to write query smt like this:

```
SELECT Person.name
     , Person.name 
  FROM Contract ....
```

problem here is first person is owner, and other is buyer..

I can get Contract -> id_realEstate and inside of this table (RealEstate) I will get id_person (owner)..

other Person.name I can get from realEstate -> id_person (than I should join with Person table)..

I tried with multiple selection before "from" but it works only if i have only 1 value, if more I get error subquery return more than 1 row.

What should I do?

Comment: Join the table twice.. `JOIN person AS owner... JOIN person AS buyer...`

Comment: But how can I reference that first one is for owner, and second for buyer?

Comment: Go on. Figure it out.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZTIRelfXQZEeZMfjZPVsMAxi757dw_hz             https://drive.google.com/open?id=19hmBO96p_l9_YjI85dyCp20_ftJNMhQw

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Finally I did it .. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!